# Why I Get "undefined" After Exporting Variables With Bash Script

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, express

I am trying to export global variables using a `Bash` script to use their values in my JS `express` API.
Here is my code:

.../Backend/index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const root_folder = process.env.ROOT_FOLDER;

app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
    res.send(root_folder);
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`));
```

../Backend/run.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export ROOT_FOLDER="~/projects/Publishing_Platform"
export PORT=5000
```

After I run `./run.sh` and the bash script is executed, I run `nodemon index.js` but the exports all say `undefined`.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help!